# What is this plastic Mitutoyo tool with retractable prongs?

Tags: identify-a-tool

Found on a local auction website.  The white parts fold down when the unit is closed.

The rear says MITUTOYO Precision Measuring System, however it looks to be plastic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My guess is that its a promotional item, not a measuring tool.  There is no part number or model number visible, and the gold paint is not something I've seen on any tools of this brand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a trade show marketing SWAG item--a retractable pocket hairbrush. Here's a [comparable item](https://www.goinginstyle.us/travel-accessories/retractable-bristle-travel-brush). I'd bet that the lateral slide switch locks it in the open position.

I have at least one Andersen Windows golf towel in my garage, and plenty of lumber yard divot repair tools, plus countless DeWalt and Thomas Tool can koozies. Serving on the builder's association board has its privileges. :D